# How to trigger Hamburger in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, hamburger-menu

What I just want is when I clicked the Hamburger then it shows menus list. Now I want when I clicked any menu then my drawerstack and drawser should be hide.

I know how to triggers button like`doClick()` but I wanna do know for  go through API but didn't successful to find any suitable answer. Could you please share your exprience how I can trigger a Hamburger in javafx.

[image]

```
HamburgerSlideCloseTransition transition = new HamburgerSlideCloseTransition(hamburger);
        transition.setRate(-1);
        hamburger.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, (e) -> {
            transition.setRate(transition.getRate() * -1);
            transition.play();
            borderpane.setRight(drawersStack);
            drawersStack.toggle(rightDrawer);
        });
```

thank you!

Comment: Your question is not really clear: What do you have? Where do you have issues with your code? What is the actual behavior and what is the supposed behavior?

Comment: How to add trigger for Hamburger?

Comment: So as far as I understand you, you want the complete drawer menu to hide when you click on any button in the drawer (as if you would click on the hamburger button when the drawer is unfolded). Why don't you add an Eventhandler to each button in your drawer, so that it toggles the transition again but in the opposite direction.

Comment: @Nash Well I appreciate your solution this a solution but this will take 50+ lines code for each menu and that will be not efficient as I want. I hope you aware about triggers methods for buttons. I just wanna know that type of solution for my hamburger.

Comment: If your buttons are all of the same custom class, you can include the event handling there (that should save you some lines). I don't know what you mean with "button triggers" . But I am pretty sure that you have to use some kind of event handling on your buttons if you want your code to execute after the click.

Comment: Just an awesome hint from your side! Thanks :+1:

Answer (score 0):

As I suggested in the comments, you could make all the buttons from the drawers from a custom class and feature the event handling there, e.g.

```
class drawerButton extends Button{

    public drawerButton(){
        addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, (e) -> {
            //open desired pane (pdf, favorites, etc)
            //close the drawer
        }
    }
}
```